# help with partitions/ changing existing partitions?

Tags: boot, partitioning

My boot partition seems to be filling up.  I assume it is from updates?  I'm a few MB from maxing it out.  Can I take from adjacent partitions without damaging data?

From Gparted

```
sda1  ext4       boot    436 of 476MB used
sda2  extended           148.5GB 
sda5 ext4        /       6.4 of 18.6GB used
unallocated              18.6GB
sda7 ext4        /home   67.8 of 107GB used
unallocated              8GB
sda6!            unknown 3.72GB
```

I think the 2 unallocated sections are from an older Ubuntu version
I don't know what unknown/sda6! partition is.  There's a little warning that it might be damaged or unable to be identified by gparted.

Answer (score 1):

If the space is being used up by updates, you can try freeing up some of this space using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

Free space can also be moved from one partition to another using GParted.
For an example of how to do this, see [Moving Space Between Partitions](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=moving-space-between-partitions).

To try to determine the contents of partition /dev/sda6 you might try the following commands:

```
sudo fdisk -l -u /dev/sda

sudo blkid /dev/sda6
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I ended up deleting old kernels and that freed up a lot of space.